# Read list of lists from text file and join and decode

Tags: python, unicode

I have a list of lists in a text file that contains non encoded unicode. Python is recognising the object being read in as a list without me doing anything like a `json.loads()`statement direct from the text file.

When I try and read all lines of the text file and then do a for loop to iterate through each sublist nothing happens. When I try encoding the entire object first before attemping to load to JSON nothing also happens.

Here is my code:

```
import glob

myglob =  'C:\\mypath\\*.txt'
myglob = ''.join(myglob)

for name in glob.glob(myglob):

    split_name = name.split('\\')[5]

    with open(name) as f:

        content = f.readlines()

        for xx in content:

            print xx.encode('utf-8')
```

The input data looks like this:

```
[['Alexis S\xe1nchez', 'Alexis', 'S\xe1nchez', 'Forward', 'Arsenal', '13', '25244'],['H\xe9ctor Beller\xedn', 'H\xe9ctor', 'Beller\xedn', 'Defender', 'Arsenal', '13', '125211'],['Libor Koz\xe1k', 'Libor', 'Koz\xe1k', 'Forward', 'Aston Villa', '24', '67285']]
```

The output should be three lines of strings with the above contents encoded. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like next code snippet?

```
listInput = [['Alexis S\xe1nchez', 'Alexis', 'S\xe1nchez', 'Forward', 'Arsenal', '13', '25244'],
  ['H\xe9ctor Beller\xedn', 'H\xe9ctor', 'Beller\xedn', 'Defender', 'Arsenal', '13', '125211'],
  ['Libor Koz\xe1k', 'Libor', 'Koz\xe1k', 'Forward', 'Aston Villa', '24', '67285']]

for listItem in listInput:

    for aItem in listItem:
        aItem = aItem.encode('utf-8')

    print (listItem)
```

**Output**:

```
==> python D:\test\Python\39708736.py
['Alexis Sánchez', 'Alexis', 'Sánchez', 'Forward', 'Arsenal', '13', '25244']
['Héctor Bellerín', 'Héctor', 'Bellerín', 'Defender', 'Arsenal', '13', '125211']
['Libor Kozák', 'Libor', 'Kozák', 'Forward', 'Aston Villa', '24', '67285']

==>
```